# ActionBar problems

Tags: error-handling, android-actionbar, android-manifest, forceclose, happening

I used the code below to create ActionBar under Api-11 and it works fine but when I want to use it in another Api-11 project, force close happens when I run the app on my device. Where is the problem?

When I make a new project and compile it and run the app on an android device it works fine!

```
package a.pkg;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActionBarActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#fc0606")));

LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
//TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
//mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

final ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) mCustomView
        .findViewById(R.id.ImageButton1);
imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

final ImageButton imageButton2 = (ImageButton) mCustomView
.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton2);
imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub



Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});

final ImageButton imageButton3 = (ImageButton) mCustomView
.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton3);
imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub



Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});


actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I foun the problem, i have to change that code manually in the manifest  from this  to this      the eclipse cannot to change minimum Api from 8 to 11 automatically.